# Difference Send-Q between netstat and ss

Tags: netstat

The ss send-Q column shows non-zero value constantly, while netstat shows Send-Q as zero for same port and same process. Can you please let me know why like this and what does mean by non-zero value.

```
root@prd-140:~# ss -lntp6 sport = :16514
State       Recv-Q    Send-Q   Local Address:Port   Peer Address:Port
LISTEN      0         1000     *:16514              *:*               users:(("libvirtd",pid=30991,fd=5),("systemd",pid=1,fd=70))
```

```
root@prd-140:~# netstat -lanpt6 |egrep 'Send|16514'
Proto    Recv-Q  Send-Q   Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp6       0      0       :::16514                :::*                    LISTEN      1/systemd
```